# Accessing any function of smart contract gives error

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I have tried to access the getAllTransactions() method which exists in my smart contract and can even be seen in console.log() but accessing it or any other method which is of smartContract whether read or write method gives error. I'm using nextjs application

```js
import { contractABI, contractAddress } from '../utils/transactions/constants'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

let ethereum
export const TransactionContext = createContext()

const TransactProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [ userAccount, setUserAccount ] = useState('')
    const [ formData, setFormData ] = useState({ 
        addressTo: '', amount: '', keyword: '', message: ''
    })
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false)
    const [ transactionCount, setTransactionCount ] = useState()
    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([])

    const handleChange = (e, name) => {
        setFormData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }))
    }

    const getContract = () => {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer)
        /*@dev::: built contract */
        // console.log(ethereum)
        // console.log(ethers)
        // console.log({
        //     provider,
        //     signer,
        //     transactionContract
        // })
        // console.log(transactionContract)
        return transactionContract
    }
    
    const getAllTxn = async() => {
        try {
            if (ethereum) {
                const transfer_contract = getContract()
                console.log(Object.keys(transfer_contract.getAllTransactions))
                // promise was not being handled and thus showed that args state for []
                const available_transactions = await transfer_contract.getAllTransactions()
                console.log(available_transactions)
                const structured_transactions = 
                    available_transactions.map((transaction) => ({
                        addressTo: transaction.receiver,
                        addressFrom: transaction.sender,
                        timestamp: new Date(transaction.timestamp.toNumber() * 1000).toLocaleString(),
                        message: transaction.message,
                        keyword: transaction.keyword,
                        amount: parseInt(transaction.amount._hex) / (10 ** 18)
                    }))
                console.log(structured_transactions)
                setTransactions(structured_transactions)
            }
            else {
                console.log('no ethereum object !')
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            throw new Error('error while parsing')
        }
    }
// ...rest of the code follows (context.js)
```

while my constants.js file is

```js
import abi from './Transfer.json'

const contractABI = abi.abi
const contractAddress= '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3'

export { contractABI, contractAddress }
```

Comment: You are talking about an error but you don't provide the error? How would anyone help without knowing what error you are seeing?